# Build a circular gauge html 5 canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I'm trying to build a circular gauge in canvas, and am having a really hard time with it. I essentially want this: [image] Just the white circle, red line, tic marks, the little ones, then a bigger one every 50, and a big tic mark with the number every 100, and the needle. I don't really care about any of the other writing on it or the silver border. Can anyone point me in the right direction? I'm pretty new to canvas but I'd like to not use any prebuilt libraries or anything.

Thanks!

Comment: You're probably going to need to read through a tutorial.

Comment: Do you have any of you know of? I've been all over google with not much luck.

Comment: I started here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a working example. I hesitated posting the entire code, because it's better when you can put it together yourself and comprehend what it's doing. It may be hard to edit this to do what you want to do, if you're not sure how it's put together. I've tried commenting what I could.

Even though it doesn't look like it, I started with Justin's example. I figured that was worth mentioning.

Click ON the gauge to increase pressure, acceleration, etc.

http://jsfiddle.net/JdLUw/

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Jason! I actually came across the getNPointsInCircle function a couple days ago when doing research for something at work so when I saw this question it just kind of fit the context I was already in.

Comment: It was just too awesome not to display.

Answer (score 2):

This is a start: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#Converting_between_polar_and_Cartesian_coordinates

I built something similar in PHP a decade ago or so.  You could use an image as the base with the tick marks (something prettier than a couple of rendered ticks) and render the hand.

http://jsfiddle.net/2zhDp/

Change your code to this for the move() method...

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('pump-discharge').getContext('2d');
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 150, 150); // clears rectangle after each move
var r = 40;
var rads = i*(Math.PI/180);
var x = r*Math.cos(rads) + 55;
var y = r*Math.sin(rads) + 55;

ctx.strokeStyle = "#D40000";
ctx.fillStyle = "#D40000";
ctx.lineWidth = 6;
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(55, 55); 
ctx.lineTo(x, y); 
ctx.stroke();
```

Comment: I tried just overlaying the needle over that image, but I found out that it wasn't that accurate and the more i moved the needle the farther off it got

Comment: Here is the needle rotating... I didn't include the image though http://jsfiddle.net/vPu3U/1/

Comment: The jsfiddle in Bill's comment is the way to go - it uses `translate` and `rotate` in the context, so the line he draws is always a simple straight line with fixed coordinates. You can do the tic marks in the same way.

Comment: @ChrisNash Are there performance implications for translating and rotating a canvas continually vs Justin's solution?

Comment: @WesleyJohnson Canvas rotate might actually perform better. You're only rotating the coordinate system, and there's always a canvas coordinate system in place. Basically you're getting the browser's (native) implementation of Canvas to do all the `r*Math.cos(angle) + x`, `r*Math.sin(angle)+y` for you, rather than manually doing it in the javascript. Perhaps more importantly, less chance to fat-finger it ;)

Answer (score 2):

Okay here ya go:

http://jsfiddle.net/77w3c/

Looks like this:

[image]

I didn't do it all for you, but it shows you how to make all of the relevant parts with no complex math. You should be able to do everything pretty easily from here.